# Why my API calls using google-api-nodejs-client to Google Analytics are not working in production?

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics-firebase, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm calling the [Google Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/?hl=pt-br) using [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) to show the number of visits inside a blog.

This blog is hosted inside Google App Engine Standard Environment.

In development, I'm authenticating my API calls using the [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production). I downloaded the JSON file with the credentials from the account service I created exclusively for analytics purposes, set the file to the Google_Application_Credentials environment variable and everything worked. I'm able to get the data from Google Analytics and display it in the website.

But this is not working in production. I suppose `getClient()` it's not getting the credentials in that environment.

Things to note: 1) I did not upload the downloaded JSON file with the credentials from the service account (I think it would be counter intuitive and unsafe to do that, and from what I understood in the docs, GCP is able to deal automatically with the API authentications);

```
const {google} = require("googleapis");

async function main () {

    // This method looks for the GCLOUD_PROJECT and GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
    // environment variables.
    const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
        // Scope of the analytics reporting,
        // with only reading access.
        scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
    });

    // Create the analytics reporting object
    const analyticsreporting = await google.analyticsreporting({
        version: 'v4',
        auth: auth,
    });

    // Fetch the analytics reporting
    const res = await analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet({...});
    return res.data;
}
```

I already run out of options. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `Google_Application_Credentials` is ALL UPPER CASE. App Engine Identity: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_credentials_on_app_engine_standard_environment

Comment: @JohnHanley, this is not the problem. As I said, everything worked well in the development environment. The problem is in the production, which is configured and handled automatically by Google Cloud.

Comment: I want to know what part is missing. I've done everything that I found in the documentation. The only thing that I haven't done is to use the [API App Engine App Identity](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/) because they didn't post anything related to Node.js yet.

Comment: I have a doubt. Do I need to upload to production my JSON file that contains my service account key and set it to `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to authenticate my API calls in production? Or this is only needed in development?

Comment: You can choose to authenticate with App Engine's default service account or by manually specifying a service account via the Json credentials file (the way you did in development).

Comment: So how do I authenticate using the App Engine's default service account? Just following the normal steps (***Google Cloud Platform > API and Services > Credentials > Create credentials > Select 'Service account key' > Choose the default App Engine service account; choose JSON as the key type > etc***)?

Comment: I provided you a link in my first comment. Read the page, it will show you the different ways.

Comment: I read that page many times. Still haven't found the solution to my problem.

Comment: The only thing that I would suggest is to read the various Google articles on how to authenticate your programs. The link I gave you has the actual code that does it.

Comment: A little more context: I created a new service account with View Permission to my project. Then I created the credentials for this service account and dowloaded the JSON. After that, I went to my Google Analytics page and granted Read and Analise Permission to this service account using the service account email created. In development I set the JSON file to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and voila...the API call worked. But when I uploaded to production, the data is not getting returned.

Comment: What you did is called service account authorization.  You can still use your JSON file. The link shows you how. You can also use App Engine Authorization. The link I gave you shows you how.

Comment: They doesn't have Node.js code as example for the Standard Environment App Engine authentication in production. Only Java, Python, Go and PHP. I don't find the App Identity API reference in Node.js library.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with the default scopes and application default credentials.  By default, if you don't create a new service account, you are going to get 'application default credentials' from the GCE metadata service:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-nodejs

Those credentials usually only have the `cloud-platform` scope, and the set of scopes cannot be changed (as of today).  To make this work, you have a few options.

1. You could create a new service account, download the service account key, and use the `keyFile` property in the `getClient` method options to reference the key.  If you do it this way, the scopes you pass into `getClient` will be respected.
2. You could play with the scopes available to the service account under which your GAE application is running.  I haven't personally tried that, but it theoretically should be possible.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi @justin-beckwith, thank you for your help. :) I already created a service account, downloaded the service account credentials and configured an environment variable to get the credentials implicitly, so I don't need to set a `keyfile` variable inside `getClient`. But I'm facing that old story, in development it works, but when I send the code to production, it doesn't. One thing that bothers me is that I didn't configured that same environment variable in production, in the GCP, which is why I think it's not working, but nothing is said in the docs that I need to do that.

Comment: The `getClient` method is able to get the credentials implicitly if my environment variable is configured: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application.

Comment: Should I replace the `analytics.readonly` scope to `cloud-platform.read-only`?

Comment: > One thing that bothers me is that I didn't configured that same environment variable in production,

You still need to set that!  You can either set that env var in production, or just pass the path to `getClient`.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work uploading the JSON credentials file and set inside `getClient` the path to it. But anyway this is unsafe and not recommended, because I'm exposing my own service account credentials. What was supposed to happen is the Google Analytics API calls get authenticated automatically by Google Cloud.